# inner query to return more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using oracle 11i in sql developer..

this is my query:

```
SELECT itm.stu_no,wm_concat(uif.names) 
FROM personal uif,Coll itm, Dep ihts
WHERE uif.stu_id IN('26',    '29',    '32')   
  and (uif.stu_no,uif.stu_no) in 
  (
       select itm.stu_no,itm.stu_test_no 
       from Col itm,Dep ihts  
       where itm.stu_no = ihts.stu_no
       AND itm.status = 'A'
       AND ihts.status = 'A'
  )
  AND itm.status = 'A'
  and  itm.stu_no=ihts.stu_no and ihts.status = 'A'
  group by itm.stu_no;
```

the inner query (marked as **strong text**) returns...

```
stu_no             stu_test_no
-----------------------------------
123                 234
```

but the complete query is not returning any rows.

this is the expected result..

```
stu_no              wm_concat(names)
------------------------------------------
123                  James Alex
234                  (null)
```

Is there any way to get the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you're asking `uif.stu_no` to be both `123` **and** `234`:
(123,123) is not in ((123,234))
and
(234,234) is not in ((123,234))

you can try this:

```
SELECT itm.stu_no,wm_concat(uif.names) 
FROM personal uif,Coll itm, Dep ihts
WHERE uif.stu_id IN('26',    '29',    '32')   
  and uif.stu_no in 
  (
       select itm.stu_no 
       from Col itm,Dep ihts  
       where itm.stu_no = ihts.stu_no
       AND itm.status = 'A'
       AND ihts.status = 'A'
       union all
       select itm.stu_test_no 
       from Col itm,Dep ihts  
       where itm.stu_no = ihts.stu_no
       AND itm.status = 'A'
       AND ihts.status = 'A'
  )
  AND itm.status = 'A'
  and  itm.stu_no=ihts.stu_no and ihts.status = 'A'
  group by itm.stu_no;
```

But why not:

```
SELECT itm.stu_no,wm_concat(uif.names) 
FROM personal uif, Coll itm, Dep ihts
WHERE uif.stu_id IN('26',    '29',    '32')   
  and (uif.stu_no = itm.stu_no OR uif.stu_no = itm.stu_test_no)
  AND itm.status = 'A'
  and itm.stu_no = ihts.stu_no 
  and ihts.status = 'A'
  group by itm.stu_no;
```

Comment: but this also did not work.. the entire query is not returning rows..

stu_no should be displayed even when wm_concat returns null..

like

stu_no    names
----------------------
123        (null)
234         (null)

Comment: Are you sure it's the inner query condition ? what values of `uif.stu_no` are there ? what does the inner query return ?

Comment: BTW, is `itm.stu_no = uif.stu_no` ?

Comment: the inner query returns 
stu_no as 123 and 234

Comment: Your original query is strange, why do you need the inner query on the first place ? why don't you just join `personal uif,Coll itm, Dep ihts` where `itm.stu_no=ihts.stu_no and (uif.stu_no=itm.stu_no OR uif.stu_no=itm.stu_test_no)` ?